# Two Linear Equations in Four Prime unknowns

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

Ben Green and Terence Tao, Linear Equations in Primes, Page 1753, Abstract,

(( .... and more generally for any (nondegenerate) problem involving two linear equations in four prime unknowns)).

Which theorem, in their article, contains the previously mentioned result ?

Or the result at least

Comment: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v171-n3-p08-p.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy I have already had the entire article

Comment: I didn't looks like a good read thanks

Comment: @Adam what do you mean ?????

Comment: I mean I did not have the linked article in my personal pdf library what did you think I meant?

Comment: An plus we are so close in rep I had to one up it and besides it was a helpful post because I got a new paper I want to read